# controlling multiple browsers during protractor e2e tests independently

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

During E2E testing of an angular web chat program, using protractor as the E2E framework, I would like to open two browsers and control each of them during the test so I can mimic a real chat and verify all expectations are fulfilled.

Is this possible? I know I can run the test in parallel on several browsers using the multi capabilities configuration segment but here I want to run multiple browsers as part of the test and perform different exceptions checks.

Any help will be most welcome,

Thanks

Alon

Comment: This feature has been requested long ago! [Protractor#381](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/381) but you might be lucky: there's a PR in progress ;)

Comment: The PR is now submitted and will be included in the next Protractor release, 1.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that does exactly what you want (i.e. test an instant messenger)

See https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/interactionConf.js and https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/interaction/interaction_spec.js#L51

To run the instant messenger test app that I'm testing against, checkout the protractor github project and run `npm start`

Comment: Also, there is a plugin that supports making screenshots and visual reports from chat alike apps. https://github.com/azachar/protractor-screenshoter-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have control over multiple browsers by forking a driver:

```js
browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
browser.addMockModule('moduleA', "angular.module('moduleA', []).value('version', '3');");

// To create a new browser.
var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();

// To create a new browser with url as 'http://www.angularjs.org':
var browser3 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
```

Note that if you use global variables or $ or $$ you have to prepare a new replacement as well

```js
var element2 = browser2.element;
var $2 = browser2.$;
var $$2 = browser2.$$;
element2(by.model(...)).click();
$2('.css').click();
$$2('.css').click();
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/browser-setup#using-multiple-browsers-in-the-same-test